# Echoing time string to log file on Solaris?

Tags: unix, echo, solaris

I am trying to echo the time a shell script executes with the following

```
EXECTIME=$(date)

echo "executed on: $EXECTIME" >> script.log
```

This was taken from a Unix tutorial but for some reason it is not working on a Solaris box with  SunOS 5.10

The error I am getting is:

> syntax error at line 2: `$EXECTIME=$' unexpected

Is there a difference in Unix and Solaris commands?

I am using usr/bin/bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not running `bash` but the legacy bourne shell `/bin/sh`.

Either replace the first line by:

```
EXECTIME=`date`
```

or set your script to use a modern shell like `ksh` or `bash` with adding this line which must be the first one of the script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `csh`, use following:

```
set EXECTIME=`date`

echo "executed on: $EXECTIME" >> script.log
```

Comment: same for bourne shell (except for the keyword 'set')

Comment: No standard /bin/sh on solaris

Comment: @serupticious, What's the output of `echo $SHELL` ?

Comment: @serupticious, The original script works perfectly for me (bash 4.2.45 + Linux)

Comment: Ok I am getting a new problem with no date time being written to the log just getting

"executed on: "

Comment: Nope now I just get "executed on: date"

Comment: @serupticious, I mean "Does typing just `date` and *Enter* in command line print date?"

Comment: @serupticious, BTW, What is the content of the line 1?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39496/discussion-between-serupticious-and-falsetru)